# Name and description of projects are null in generated pom: how to fix it?

Tags: maven, gradle

Using gradle 1.11, I generate a repository pom file when uploading using the following code:

```
[
    install.repositories.mavenInstaller,
    uploadArchives.repositories.mavenDeployer
]*.pom*.whenConfigured { pom ->
    pom.project {
        name "${name}";
        packaging "jar";
        description "${description}";
        url "${projectURL}";

        scm {
            // everything OK here
        }

        licenses {
            // everything OK here
        }

        developers {
            // everything OK here
        }
    }   
}
```

"Up" in the build file I define:

```
project.ext {
    description = "the description here";
}
```

and expect `name` to be derived from the project name.

Yet, in the generated pom file (taken from my local repository), I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>OK here</groupId>
  <artifactId>OK here</artifactId>
  <version>OK here</version>
  <!-- Oops... -->
  <name>null</name>
  <description>null</description>
  <url>OK here</url>
  <licenses>
      <!-- All the rest is OK -->
```

The code above is copy/pasted from an external project and I haven't touched it since I don't really understand what it does... But there is definitely a bug. I want the name and description to appear...

Is it in gradle? Is it in the code itself?

**EDIT** OK, the following works:

- move the `description` declaration out of `project.ext`;
- refer to `${project.name}` instead of `${name}`, and `${project.description}` instead of `${description}`.

Comment: Try `project.description` and `project.name`. There's no need for GString and curly braces here.

Comment: @Opal What do you call GString?

Comment: This is GString `${project.description}` while could be just `project.description`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the existing `project.description` property (not an extra property) and don't explicitly set the POM's `name` and `description`. They will default to `project.name` and `project.description`, respectively.

(As to what happens in the current code, `project.ext.description` will be shadowed by `project.description` (which is still `null`), and `name "${name}"` is a self-assignment of `pom.name`.)

Comment: Hmm, OK, so, replacing the ext variable with `description = "whatever"` works; I also tried and replaced `${name}` with `${project.name}`, same with `${descrption}`. However, if I don't explicitly set `name` and `description`, they do not appear in the generated pom file... Note: gradle 1.11; I'll edit my question

Comment: Strange. I never ever configured these explicitly, but they are always contained in my POMs. What happens if you comment out the whole `whenConfigured` part?

Comment: OK, maybe I should clarify something first; I am talking about the pom files generated in repositories. That is, locally, in `~/.m2/repository/path/to/group/thename/theversion/thename-theversion.pom`. Are we talking about the same file?

Comment: Yes. What else could we be talking about? :-) `name`, `description`, and `packaging` will be set automatically. `<packaging>jar</packaging>` won't show up in the generated POM (even if set explicitly) because it's the Maven default, and the Maven libraries used underneath by Gradle will not generate this "redundant" information.

Comment: Well, if I comment out the whole `whenConfigured` section, `name` and `description` don't appear either... Nor do the license/author sections etc...

Comment: Of course license etc. won't appear (the idea was to diagnose the problem). If name and description also don't appear, there's either something wrong elsewhere in the build, or it's a bug in this particular Gradle version. Anyway, leaving that part in won't hurt.

Comment: I intend to change gradle version soon anyway so I see how this will turn out! Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Thank you" on SO is +1 or accept. Otherwise I'll never catch up with you.